# How to fix the error "unknown variable datadir" in mysql on raspbian?

Tags: mysql, raspbian

I want to safe the Databases on an Usbstick and not on my RaspberryPi.

First I did:

- service mysql stop
- mkdir /media/pi/EMTEC/mysql
- nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf 
  and changed datadir=/media/pi/EMTEC/mysql
- cp -Rv /var/lib/mysql/* /media/usb4/mysql/
- chown -R mysql:mysql /media/usb4/mysql/

which worked without problems

My my.cnf:

```
[client-server]

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/

!includedir /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/

datadir=/media/pi/EMTEC/mysql
```

When trying to restart the mysql service I receive:

> mysql: unknown variable 'datadir=/media/pi/EMTEC/mysql'

How do I fix that error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `datadir` to `[mysqld]` section. `datadir` is a global variable to configure mysql server.

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/your/new/dir/
```

Answer (score 0):

The above solution didn't solve my problem.

I did move the datadir under [mysqld] but it was giving errors for other files, so I moved all below files under [mysqld].

like below and it fixed issues at my end.

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```